# Сортировка по одному из значений в словаре Python

Tags: python, словари

Подскажите плиз как можно почистить словарь от тех данных, у которых в значение число меньше, чем у того, которое с таким же именем в значении. Для примера приведу код:

```
old_dict = {
    1: (100, 'dima'),
    2: (200, 'vova'),
    3: (300, 'oleg'),
    4: (400, 'vova'),
    5: (500, 'sasha')
}
new_dict = {}
```

В new_dict должны оказаться все записи из old_dict кроме **2: (200, 'vova')**, так как есть **4: (400, 'vova')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собрал словарь с ключом-именем и значением индексом+значением

```
old_dict = {
    1: (100, 'dima'),
    2: (200, 'vova'),
    3: (300, 'oleg'),
    4: (400, 'vova'),
    5: (500, 'sasha'),
    6: (250, 'dima'),
    7: (150, 'dima'),
    8: (200, 'oleg'),
}
name_by_values = dict()
for i, (value, name) in old_dict.items():
    if name not in name_by_values:
        name_by_values[name] = i, value
    else:
        _, old_value = name_by_values[name]
        if value > old_value:
            name_by_values[name] = i, value

new_dict = {
    i: (value, name)
    for name, (i, value) in name_by_values.items()
}
print(new_dict)

# Тоже самое с сортировкой по номеру
new_sorted_dict = {
    i: (value, name)
    for name, (i, value) in sorted(name_by_values.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])
}
print(new_sorted_dict)
```

Результат:

```
{6: (250, 'dima'), 4: (400, 'vova'), 3: (300, 'oleg'), 5: (500, 'sasha')}
{3: (300, 'oleg'), 4: (400, 'vova'), 5: (500, 'sasha'), 6: (250, 'dima')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, можно как-то проще, но если в лоб решать задачу, то нужно сначала пересобрать данные в словарь с ключами-именами и списком значений, а потом можно уже найти и оставить максимальное значение и опять пересобрать словарь в исходный вид:

```
old_dict = {
    1: (100, 'dima'),
    2: (200, 'vova'),
    3: (300, 'oleg'),
    4: (400, 'vova'),
    5: (500, 'sasha')
}

temp_dict = {}
for k1,v1 in old_dict.items():
    v2,k2 = v1
    temp_dict[k2] = temp_dict.get(k2, [])
    temp_dict[k2].append((k1,v2))

print(temp_dict)

new_dict = {}
for k1,v1 in temp_dict.items():
    k2,v2 = max(v1, key=lambda x: x[1])
    new_dict[k2] = (v2,k1)

print(new_dict)
```

Вывод:

```
{
  'dima': [(1, 100)], 
  'vova': [(2, 200), (4, 400)],
  'oleg': [(3, 300)],
  'sasha': [(5, 500)]
}

{
  1: (100, 'dima'),
  4: (400, 'vova'),
  3: (300, 'oleg'),
  5: (500, 'sasha')
}
```